# How to correctly setup REDIS with DDEV / DOCKER for Laravel local?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, redis, ddev

I am looking to setup Redis in my local dev environment, I am using DDEV in Laravel Projects.

I've followed the steps here to add redis to the project:
https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/docker-compose-services/redis

After a `ddev restart` I can see Redis is getting pulled into the container however it instantly falls over which you can see from running a `docker ps -a`.

[image]

Please would somebody be able to help with the correctly setting this up for a laravel project?

Just for reference I am on a MacbookAir 2021 BigSur M1 Chipset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE 2023: Use [github.com/drud/ddev-redis](https://github.com/drud/ddev-redis) and ensure your redis server connection is set to `redis` in config. I just had to change redis host in `database.php` connection `127.0.0.1` to `redis` in a laravel 4.2 project to work locally.

===================================

To get this working locally:

I updated the `docker-compose.redis.yaml` to the following:

```
# ddev redis recipe file
#
version: "3.6"

services:
  redis:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
    volumes:
      - ".:/mnt/ddev_config"
      - "./redis:/usr/local/etc/redis"
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]
  web:
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis:redis
```

Actual changes to file:

```
image: redis:latest
```

```
command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]
```

And in the projects `.env` file set:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
```

Now the Redis container remains available:
[image]

Can now trigger and process correctly via:

```
ddev artisan queue:work redis --queue=mycustomqueue
```

Comment: If the recipe in https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/docker-compose-services/redis is incorrect, could you please make a PR there? It worked OK last I tried it. But it's not oriented at Laravel, so maybe that's the issue? Looks to me like the biggest issue might have just been the REDIS_HOST=redis in your .env.

Comment: Thanks for the reply rfay, I've double checked on this and if I return the command line to:
`command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]`
Then this results in the redis container immediately falling over upon a ddev restart even though REDIS_HOST=redis is set in the .env. Changing the command line to:
`command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]`
This allows redis to spin up successfully for me.
I've created a branch for this in the project however do not have to permission to push a branch and then create a pull request?

Comment: If you're asking how to create a PR in ddev-contrib... Like most open-source projects, you create a fork, then a branch in the fork, then create a PR.

Comment: Cheers, this is my first open-source forking so appreciate the guidance. I've created a PR for this now.

Comment: Here's an article about Symfony with ddev, https://blog.michaelbrooks.dev/easy-laravel-development-with-docker-using-ddev/

Comment: These days, the official add-on would be better, https://github.com/drud/ddev-redis 
 `ddev get drud/ddev-redis`